# How to open dialog for file download in JQuery after Ajax Call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Working with IE-10/11

I am downloading a file in JQuery

```
Common.ajax({
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'GET',
    url: link,
    data: {'_CONV_ID': convId},
    success: function (data) {
        alert("File DOwnloaded" + data);
       //How to say Browser to open dialog to open, save cancel the file download
    },
    error: function (result) {
        $.unblockUI();
        $.log(result.responseText);
    }
});
```

Alert message successfully getting displayed on screen but dialog to save or open file does not appear. Anyone suggest what to write in success to get that?

Comment: "data" is your file url?

Comment: It must be Byte Array which we are getting in response. You may suggest more parameters which i can add here

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var fileurl=  window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
a.href =  fileurl;
a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
delete a;
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileurl);
```

byteArray should be from your data

Comment: Oh It displays file inside web browser. It should give download dialog instead of changing page

Comment: also it is giving stay on page and leave the page dialog

Answer (score 0):

[Bluish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660817/107768) is completely right about this, you can't do it through Ajax because JavaScript cannot save files directly to a user's computer (out of security concerns). Unfortunately pointing the *main window's* URL at your file download means you have little control over what the user experience is when a file download occurs.

I created [jQuery File Download](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) which allows for an "Ajax like" experience with file downloads complete with OnSuccess and OnFailure callbacks to provide for a better user experience. Take a look at my [blog post](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) on the common problem that the plugin solves and some ways to use it and also a [demo of jQuery File Download in action](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/). Here is the [source](http://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js)

Here is a simple use case demo using the plugin [source](http://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js) with promises. The [demo page](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/) includes many other, 'better UX' examples as well.

```
$.fileDownload('some/file.pdf')
    .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
    .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
```

Comment: It is not working for my case. My link contains QueryString which it is not picking for IE10/IE11